# Create a boot sector on correct drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot

My configuration was:

- Primary drive (with Windows on it) is an SSD with the drive letter C
- My secondary drive is a hard drive that has two partition on it, E and F.

When I upgraded to Windows 10, for unknown reasons, my boot sector went to the HDD (not sure if E or F) while Windows was still on the C drive.

Then, my HDD drive stopped working correctly and my system didn't boot.

I want to boot from the SSD and replace my broken HDD.

**Now, the really tricky part:**
My computer is a laptop with a broken screen. 
I must connect it to a TV using an HDMI connector.
Unfortunately, it will recognize the TV only when Windows boots up. As I don't have a screen on the laptop, I cannot use any recovery console.

So my only solution is to take the SSD, put it in another computer and find a way to solve this using another computer. Any command that I found in this forum seem risky to me as I'm not on the computer with trouble.

How can I create a boot sector on a drive that will be used on another computer?

I hope you got an idea because I feel like in a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

This takes more than just inserting the correct boot sector. The Boot Configuration Database (BCD) must also be either re-created or reconciled.

The solution here is to:

1. Take the SSD to another computer
2. Insert it as the sole hard disk drive onto that computer (Unplug its existing HDD or SSD)
3. Boot from a Windows installation disc or USB
4. Run automatic boot repair
5. Shut down and return the SSD

**Under no circumstances allow that makeshift computer to boot from your SSD.** It may be a good idea to make a sector-by-sector backup of the SSD beforehand, in the even that it happened.